How do I configure Deno to work with npm:preact imports?
Whenever I try to create JSX elements in my .tsx files like so:
const myElem = <p></p>

my IDE gives me the following two errors:

JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements' exists. deno-ts(7026)


Cannot find name 'h'. deno-ts(2304)

I can easily fix the issue by importing h in all of my tsx files:
import { h } from "$preact";

but I'd really like for this to be imported automatically somehow.
I tried adding "jsxImportSource": "$preact" to the compilerOptions in deno.json, but that gives me the following error when I try to run my application:

'jsxImportSource' is only supported when 'jsx' is set to 'react-jsx' or 'react-jsxdev'

And when I try to set the jsx compiler option to react-jsx as the error message suggests, I get:

Failed to resolve the specifier ""$preact/jsx-runtime"" as its after-prefix
portion ""jsx-runtime"" could not be URL-parsed relative to the URL prefix
"npm:preact@10.20.2/" mapped to by the prefix "$preact/"

What is the correct configuration required to get Deno to treat jsx correctly?

I'm not sure whether using the npm package is a supported pattern. [tag:preact] is a foundation for [tag:freshjs] — which is maintained by a Deno core member — so I'd use it as a model. You can examine how Fresh uses Preact with an import-mapped CDN (currently esm.sh and likely jsr.io in the future). See its deno.json and import map files. If this meets your needs and you'd like to see it as an answer, let me know.

@jsejcksn I've managed to get this to work in past projects with esm.sh like you described. But I frequently kept running into issues where esm.sh would randomly respond with the 500 status code, so I try to avoid it where possible.

^ @Jespertheend Well, that was just an example of a CDN which bundles and serves types, but you can choose whichever CDN is preferable. The network availability of a particular CDN seems unrelated to this question, and the Deno CLI has tools that mitigate network dependency availability issues (e.g. cache, vendor, etc.) — eviction of the local dependency cache is a manual process.

@jsejcksn Yeah that makes sense, I'm just trying to justify why I want to use npm: imports haha. If there's no way to configure Deno this way, I think I'd prefer to just import h everywhere instead of switching to remote imports.
